# How to identify if one YouTrack workflow was triggered by another

Tags: javascript, youtrack

**Workflow A** is an on-change workflow that checks to see if the last person who updated an issue was in the Global Developers group. If not the expiration date field gets extended by 48 hours.

**Workflow B** is an on-schedule workflow that leaves comments on issues based on the expiration date.

When someone who is not in the Global Developers group was the last user to update the ticket

1. Workflow A extends the expiration date by 48 hours
2. Workflow B leaves a comment 24 hours before the expiration date
3. That comment kicks off Workflow A, which checks to see what group the updater is in
   `ctx.issue.updatedBy.isInGroup("Global Developers")`
4. The updater wasn't in the Global Developers group, so the expiration date gets extended by 48 hours

   *(And then the loop continues until I catch it and manually fix the expiration date)*

In step 3 how can I ignore updates made by Workflow B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An onSchedule rule is executed on behalf of a special system user, its login starts with 'workflow_user_'. You can access the login via ctx.currentUser.login.